# Powershell CSOM Sharepoint online list permission

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I've been writing a script to connect to SharePoint online, create a document library and add some AD accounts to the permission. I've written all the code using snippets I have found through many searches but am having an issue with the permissions part.

I keep getting an error when adding the user and permission type to roledefinitionbinding.
The error is:

Collection has not been initialized at line 0 char 0.

Here is my code

```
$collRdb = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
$collRdb.Add($role)
$collRoleAssign = $web.RoleAssignments;
$ctx.Load($principal)
$collRoleAssign.Add($principal, $collRdb)

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The issue is when it runs $collRoleAssign.Add($principal, $collRdb) part and stop with the error above.

I would really appreciate a hand with this before my PC get launched out of the window.

Thanks
Mark

*EDIT*

All of the code is taken from this page:

http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2012/06/07/scripting-sharepoint-online-with-powershell-using-client-object-model/

The only change is i'm using the get principal fun instead of the get group, but not sure if that's what has done it. I'm very new to powershell.

Thanks

Comment: You gave us a snippet of code, but it references variables that we have no idea what they are. What is $principal? What is $web? What is $role? What is $ctx?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add something into $collRoleAssign if it's not loaded before.
You get an error because it has null value.

I would have wrote it like this:

```
$collRoleAssign = $web.RoleAssignments
$ctx.Load($collRoleAssign)
```

Comment: I suppose you already set $principal before

```
$ctx.Load($principal)
```

Comment: here I suppose $collRdb is set and loaded

```
$collRoleAssign.Add($principal, $collRdb)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

By the way there is a ";" in your code which should not be there

I didn't try it but that should help!

Sylvain